# querying all fields in neo4j index using python-embedded bindings

Tags: python, lucene, neo4j

I'm trying to query a node index across all fields. This is what I thought would work:

```
idx = db.node.indexes.get('myindex')
idx.query('*:search_query')
```

But this returns no results. However, this works

```
idx = db.node.indexes.get('myindex')
idx.query('*:*')
```

And it returns all the nodes in the index as expected. Am I wrong in assuming that the first version should work at all?

Comment: I don't know neo4j well enough to be certain, but a query returning all values in a Lucene index uses different logic than a standard search.  It wouldn't surprize me at all if "*:*" was treated as a token to signal returning all records explicitly, and syntax like "*:term" was not supported at all.  Considering Lucene's indexing scheme, supporting a search like that would be difficult.

Comment: Unless when adding documents, new searchable terms were automatically added to a catchall, search-everything field, that is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect the first version to work, and am surprised the second does. Neo4j parses those queries using [this Lucene syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)- I don't see anything about wildcard fields. Instead, remove the field to search against an implied "all fields".

Plug - for an easier way to build Lucene queries (compatible with Neo4j), check out [lucene-querybuilder](https://github.com/scholrly/lucene-querybuilder). It's used by [neo4j-rest-client](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client) and [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django).

EDIT:

I can't seem to find support for the "all fields" implicit search I thought existed- sorry! I guess you'll just have to manually include all fields in the query (eg, "name:falmarri OR userType:falmarri").

Comment: i'm also suprised the second works. usually in my case i can do smthing like `'myindex_param:*'` but never `'*:param_value'`.

Comment: `Instead, remove the field to search against an implied "all fields".` Are you suggesting that `idx.query('my_query')` will query against all fields? I just tried that and I'm getting a java.lang.NPE

Comment: That's unfortunate- that's exactly what I was suggesting. Is the index configured as fulltext?

Comment: @MattLuongo: No, my index is created via `db.node.indexes.create('myindex', type='exact', to_lower_case='true')`.

Comment: AFAIK Lucene query syntax only works for fulltext-configured indices.